# Updating "To:" Email-Header in a while loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mime, multipart, smtplib

Below is a code to send multiple emails to contacts loaded from a text file.

```
import time
    from time import sleep

    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    import smtplib

    uname = #testmail@gmail.com
    name = "KTester"
    password = #password1
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(uname, password)
    message="Test"

    msg = MIMEMultipart('Alternative')
    f= open("list.txt","r")clear

    if f.mode == "r":
      cont = f.read().splitlines()
      for x in cont:
        print time.ctime()

        msg['Subject'] = "Test Mail - cripted Sample"
        msg['To'] = x
        msg['From'] = name+"\x0A\x0D"+uname
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'html'))

        print "successfully sent email to %s:" % (msg['To'])

    f.close()
    server.quit()
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

In this case, the first compilation is the expected outcome, which we can get if we use `print "successfully sent email to %s:" % (x)`

The Variable 'x' changes its value at the end of each iteration.

However, msg['To'] = x does not accept value from second iteration of the loop(The second code run above).

Assignment operation does not work on the message object.

Kindly help with whats going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is by design.

Reassigning to `msg['to']` doesn't overwrite the existing mail header, it adds another.  To send the existing message to a new address you need to delete the 'to' header before setting it.

```
del msg['to']
msg['to'] = 'spam@example.com'
```

This applies to other headers too.  From the docs for [`Message.__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html):

> Note that this does not overwrite or delete any existing header with
>   the same name. If you want to ensure that the new header is the only
>   one present in the message with field name name, delete the field
>   first, e.g.:
>
> `del msg['subject']`
>
> `msg['subject'] = 'Python roolz!'`

Answer (score 0):

(Edit of original answer, after clarification of question's output)

Try moving the following line into the for loop:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('Alternative')
```

To look like this:

```
for x in cont:
    msg = MIMEMultipart('Alternative')
    print time.ctime()

    msg['Subject'] = "Test Mail - cripted Sample"
    msg['To'] = x
    msg['From'] = name+"\x0A\x0D"+uname
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'html'))

    print "successfully sent email to %s:" % (msg['To'])
```

I think the msg needs to be new in each iteration.

My testing yielded exactly the same results - appearing to send to the same email address over and over. Because the msg headers simply get appended to. The for loop was creating multiple to: headers, but printing was only revealing the first. See below for what it looks like in debug:

[Header of To: line in original for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq0RR.png)

[Output of original for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZBDU.png)

After adding the msg instantiation to within the for loop, the output was as expected with different names each iteration.

I think the root of how msg is structured might be that email can have more than one person on the to: line. The above solution presumes that you only wanted one person on each to: line.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip, but it did not work. I have made some changes to the Question could you check it once again.

Comment: Edited original answer. I'm not an expert in MIMEMultipart so there may be a limitation in adding the msg within the for loop, but provided you're also sending that message within the for loop - it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your script is that you have defined **msg = MIMEMultipart('Alternative')** outside ***for loop***. Try defining **msg = MIMEMultipart('Alternative')** inside ***for loop***.

> The solution is same as given by **@Daniel Sims** but I have turned your script more readable so that everyone can understand

I have edited your code in my own way which worked like a charm for me. Have a try:

**[CODE]**

```
import time
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# credentials    
uname = 'your email address'
name = "KTester"
password = 'password'

# Connecting to gmail server and logging to your gmail account
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
server.starttls()
server.login(uname, password)

message = "Test"  # Your message

with open('list.txt', 'r') as lst:
    lines = lst.readlines()  # Reading files to get emails

    for line in lines:  # Getting each email from list of emails
        msg = MIMEMultipart('Alternative')   # This line is added here(which if you have did outside of the for loop)
        msg['Subject'] = "Test Mail - cripted Sample"
        msg['To'] = line
        msg['From'] = '{}{}{}'.format(name, "\x0A\x0D", uname)
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'html'))

        print(time.ctime())
        print("successfully sent email to {}".format(msg['To']))

 server.quit()
```